# return html using JS without document.append?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

This is my function to create the button

```js
function createMp3Button(title, mp3Path) {
  let button = document.createElement("button")
  button.innerHTML = "click me"
  button.onclick = function () {
    ahk.ButtonOpenMp3(event, mp3Path)
    return false
  }
  return button
  // $(".results").append(button)
}
```

I can use Jquery and append the button an a div/element or the body of the HTML page for example. However, how do I just return the button and create the element wherever I call the function?

For example, I'm calling createMp3Button several times and without having to worry about where the div I'm calling it, is there a way to just call the function and have it create the button where I called the JS function?

At the current moment, return just the "button" as in the function currently I get this instead

```
[object HTMLButtonElement]
```

Comment: You're returning the button correctly. The problem is in the code that calls this. It needs to append the button to the DOM, not use it as a string.

Comment: You code already does that. It creates and returns a button element. What you're showing is the "toString()" result, so whatever you're giving that button to is doing the wrong thing. However, notes on your code: don't use` .innerHTML` for setting text, use `.innerText`. Also, don't use the ancient `.onclick` attribute, register a normal event handler using `button.addEventListener("click", ...)` instead. And that event handler doesn't need to return `false`, that hasn't done anything in years =)

Comment: You could use `return button.outerHTML`, but that will lose the event listener, since it's not part of the HTML.

Comment: `$(".results").append( createMp3Button("Some title", "https://example.com") )`

Comment: Thank you everyone! Apologies for not adding the function I was adding it as I thought just calling the function with given params was utilizing my function correctly. I guess I was too zoned in that it was my function return wrong and not "how" I was calling the function. Ty guys, that solved my problem. Cheers!

@Mike'Pomax'Kamermans , ty for your help and your suggestions. Really appreciate your explanations and helping me improve my code. Cheers!

Comment: you can try JS built-in function `appendChild()`. works the same way JQuery Append does